# How to fix a syntax error: unexpected end of file in bash script

Tags: bash

This is the code, when I am trying to run it on Putty it comes up with a syntax error at the end of the code : unexpected end of file. I've been staring at this for a few hours and I cannot figure out what is wrong. There is a directory called assessment and it only has an empty text file named: file2.txt . I am running the script from the home directory that contains the assessment directory.

```
#Bash Command Menu
#!/bin/bash
#Creates the file needed in the choices
if [ [ ! -f assessment/file1.txt ] ]

then
        touch assessment/file1.txt
fi

#Prints the welcoming message
echo "Greetings '$USER' , this is the menu"
#while loop menu
while [ [ $choice != "5" ] ]
do
        #Shows the choices
        echo "The choices are:"
        echo "1. Delete the file: file1.txt"
        echo "2. View the contents of file2.txt with wordcount and line numbers"
        echo "3. View all the running processes"
        echo "4. View all files and directories withing home"
        echo "5. Exit menu"
        echo -n "What is your choice?"

        #Reads what the user inputs
        read $choice

        #Choice1 - Delete file1.txt or prompt an error if the file has already been deleted
        if [ $choice == "1" ]
        then
            echo "Choice 1 picked!"
                if [ [ -f assessment/file1.txt ] ]
            then
                rm assessment/file1.txt
                echo "File deletion successfull"
            else
                echo "The file does not exist"
                fi
        fi
        #Choice 2 - Prompt file2.txt with wordcount and line numbers
        if [ $choice == "2" ]
        then
            echo "Choice 2 picked!"
            echo "Opening file: file2.txt"
            cat -n assessment/file2.txt
            echo "Counting words.."
            wc -w assessment/file2.txt
        fi
        #Choice 3 - Show running processes
        if [ $choice == "3" ]
        then
            echo "Choice 3 picked!"
            echo "All running processes"
            ps -aux
        fi
        #Choice 4 - Show all files and directories in home
        if [ $choice == "4" ]
        then
            echo "Choice 4 picked!"
            echo "Displaying all files and directories"
            ls -R $HOME     
        fi
done
#Printing the good bye message
echo "Exiting menu, have a great day!"
exit;
```

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: replace `if [ [ ... ] ]` with `if [[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @Socowi : Of course this is an error, but how does it explain **this** error message? I would rather expect a syntax error about the second, lone, `]`  in the code.